# BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS on Kubuntu 19.10 Boot hangs

Tags: kubuntu, 19.10

I'm doing a clean install on  a Lenovo P52 that also dual boots with windows 10 on another drive.   The ISO install worked great and the install finished.  I reboot and then OS eventually gives me message about BIOS containing WGDS but no WRDS
Once that message is displayed - the boot appears to hang and no login UI is displayed.
I am able to go to console though so the machine is running.
Booting in recovery mode and then activating network and contusing in the boot works fine.

Any ideas on how to resolve this???  What does this message mean?

Comment: This message is unrelated to the boot problem.

Comment: Google "BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS"

Comment: Yes the blocking appears to have been the video drivers - I changed video settings in bios and the machine now boots into a login screen.

Answer (score 1):

This laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad P52. Some models of Lenovo ThinkPads have settings in the BIOS that can be changed in the Graphics Device menu which has options for integrated graphics, discrete graphics and switchable graphics . After changing the display graphics settings in the BIOS, Kubuntu 19.10 was able to boot to the login screen.

[image: Lenovo BIOS Graphics Device menu]

*Setting the BIOS card configuration to Switchable on my Lenovo Legion allowed the UI to load.* <sup>[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205411/bios-contains-wgds-but-no-wrds-on-kubuntu-19-10-boot-hangs/1237303#1237303)</sup>

Comment: Setting the BIOS card configuration to "Switchable" on my Lenovo Legion allowed the UI to load.